# Angular2 auto suggestion giving undefined value

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, autosuggest

Trying to implement auto suggestion with angular

```
 $ npm install ng2-auto-complete --save
```

add map and packages to systemjs.config.js

```
 map['ng2-auto-complete'] = 'node_modules/ng2-auto-complete/dist';
 packages['ng2-auto-complete'] = { main: 'ng2-auto-complete.umd.js', ...]
```

Added the component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'person',
    templateUrl: 'app/person/person.component.html'
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: FormGroup;   
    staffInfo :  PersonalMastModel[];
    public arrayOfKeyValues2: any[] = [
    {key:1, name:'Key One'}, 
    {key:2, name:'Key Two'}, 
    {key:3, name:'Key Three'},
    {key:4, name:'Key Four'}
  ];
personalData(personName: String): Observable<DepartmentModel[]>{
        let headers = new Headers();        
            if(personName!= undefined){

                headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
                headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                return this.http.post(AppUtils.GET__MASTER_URL //return a list of department
               ,{personName:personName}
               ,{headers:headers})
               .map(response => response.json())
               .catch(this.handleError);
            }


    }
...............
```

In person.component.html added the tag

```
 <input auto-complete [source]="arrayOfKeyValues2"
      [(ngModel)]="model3"
      placeholder="enter text"
      value-property-name="key"
      display-property-name="name"/>selected: {{model3 | json}}<br/><br/>
```

Here in dropdown its coming as (undefined) undefined.
[image]

Also How can I change this, So that each time will fetch data from server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using objects instead of strings, you need to use the `list-formatter` attribute to invoke the value formatter.

```
 [list-formatter]="listFormatter"
 value-property-name="key"
 display-property-name="name">
```

and define the `listFormatter` as

```
listFormatter = (data: any) => `<span>(${data.key}) ${data.name}</span>`;
```

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFiElop4tpvrOXGAqZhU?p=preview) example with your code.

---

- *Also How can I change this, So that each time will fetch data from server side?*

You can use the `valueChanged` attribute to bind it to a function that fetches data from the server, though this is an entirely separate question.

Comment: In documentation its mentioned : valueChanged / ngModelChange, callback function that is executed when a new dropdown is selected. e.g. (valueChanged)="myCallback($event)" -  Invoked when a new value is selected from dropdown not during the typing.

Comment: Yes, and wasn't that what you wanted? You make your server call in your callback function!

Comment: No, not on Onselect, its more on on keypress

Comment: That will be an awful lot of server calls. May I ask why? Perhaps it would be wiser to load it in the background beforehand and just display it on key press?